# Class wont serialize java

Tags: java, serialization

Sorry if this was already asked but I am having some problems serializing classes I made. I have tested Strings and Array Lists but when I try a NoteCard, a class made of two Strings, I get errors when serializing and obviously deserializing. These are the errors I get when running the program.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.leopoldmarx.note.notecard.NoteCard
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.leopoldmarx.note.program.Driver.main(Driver.java:22)
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.leopoldmarx.note.notecard.NoteCard
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.leopoldmarx.note.program.Driver.main(Driver.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.leopoldmarx.note.notecard.NoteCard
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.leopoldmarx.note.program.Driver.main(Driver.java:22)
```

The code for the errors is the following:

```
NoteCard test = new NoteCard("this is the front", "this is the back");
System.out.println(test.getFront() + test.getBack());
try {

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("hey.cardset"));
    oos.writeObject(test);
    oos.close();
}

catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("hey.cardset"));
    NoteCard n1 = (NoteCard) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(n1.getFront() + n1.getBack());
}

catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have looked all over the internet and looked through a few books and found nothing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure your `NoteCard` class implements `java.io.Serializable` and its fields also do it or they are declared using a primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `NoteCard` implements `java.io.Serializable` interface

```
public class NoteCard implements java.io.Serializable
```

and also if `NoteCard` contains other class members, then make sure they are also implementing `java.io.Serializable`.

When you want to serialize a class, always calculate a `serialVersionUID`, and most of the IDE's will do it for you. If  you don't provide one, then java will do it for you when you serialize, but it's not recommended.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3457676767677L;
```

Comment: *When you want to serialize a class, always calculate a serialVersionUID* that's not necessary at all, in fact that field is useless.